# "SIS ESCAPE" message on dash of 2015 Isuzu NQR?

Tags: diesel, isuzu

Does anyone know what the this message means? I can't find any references to it online.

Comment: Is this a specialized vehicle? Or standard equipment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since discovered that our drivers switched the display to Spanish, and that SIS ESCAPE is Spanish for EXH. SYSTEM - alerting the driver to an issue with the emissions control system. Requires dealer inspection/service.